# How to delete files in hidden directory?

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to delete all files having a name starting with liste_concepteur_matiere :

```
del C:\liste_concepteur_matiere*.pdf /S
```

The problem is that when the file is located in AppData\Local\Temp\ then I get access denied error. So how to enable deletion of those files ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make possible deletion of a file in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349167/how-to-make-possible-deletion-of-a-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open cmd like administrator:
right click on its icon and "run as administrator".

Comment: Try to run your application as administrator